# The network's train loss and validation loss become low after only a few epochs

Tags: regression, train

I am using wireless data(I-Q data) to do regression task, and I just use the amplitude of that data as input. The backbone of the network is 1 Conv-BN-RELU layer, 4 ResNet Blocks and a fully connection layer, the loss is smooth-L1 loss. But the network's train loss and validation loss become very low and the loss at the begining is also very low. And I have also test the trained model on several test dataset. The test loss is also low, and the loss at this level is acceptable for my task.

Loss figure:

[image: loss figure]

Although its generalization has been tested by my test set, I still want to ask if I can trust this model and why this phenomenon occurs?

Because my data is neither images nor text. It is not very common, so I would like to ask you if you have any experience and advice on this issue, without limiting yourself to input data type.

Comment: After some testing, there is no problem with such data curves, but for my dataset and task, the loss at the beginning of training and validation is already so small that they look strange.